# Auto insertion of values in pop up text fields using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do auto-insertion of values to the fields inside the pop up(see attached image)   using the code below. But the insertion of values to the fields is not happening using the automation code below.

Would appreciate, if someone can provide the reason and solution for the same.

Any help is appreciated:

[image]

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class test9 {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
private WebElement foundElement;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.url.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void test9() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/Login.aspx");
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr362_Login_Login_DNN_txtUsername")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr362_Login_Login_DNN_txtUsername")).sendKeys("comp-da@comp.com");//dummy username
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr362_Login_Login_DNN_txtPassword")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr362_Login_Login_DNN_txtPassword")).sendKeys("password");//dummy password
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_ctr362_Login_Login_DNN_cmdLogin")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='Nav']/span/span/div[3]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_cd_Banner_Customer_b")).click();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    WebElement userName = find(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_email\"]"),"abc@gmail.com");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_firstname"),"Abc");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_lastname"),"R");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_firstname"),"test1");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_lastname"),"abc");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_password"),"password");
    find(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_passwordconfirm"),"password");
    search(By.id("dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_create_b_input"));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.Controls")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink")).click();
}




@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public WebElement find(By by,String keys){
    By byy = by;
    String key=keys;
    System.out.println(by.toString()+keys.toString());
    for (int milis=0; milis<3000; milis=milis+3000) {
        try {
            foundElement = driver.findElement(by);
            //driver.findElement(by).clear();
            driver.findElement(by).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            foundElement.sendKeys("");
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            foundElement.sendKeys(keys);
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            foundElement.sendKeys(keys);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }

    }
    return foundElement;

}

public WebElement search(By by){
    By byy = by;

    for (int milis=0; milis<3000; milis=milis+3000) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by).click();
            driver.findElement(by).click();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        }
    }
    return foundElement;
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
        } else {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
        return alert.getText();
    } finally {
        acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

Including the html which contains Email, First Name, Last Name etc.

```
<div id="Heading">
<span id="dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDA">Create DA</span>
<span class="nyk_ButtonSpan">
</div>
<table id="dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin" class="nykTable" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="nykRow">
<td class="nykCreateLbl" style="vertical-align: top">
<td class="nykCreateEntry">
</tr>
<tr class="nykRow">
<tr class="nykRow">
<tr class="nykRow">
<tr class="nykRow">
<tr id="dnn_ctr384_View_CreateDealerAdmin_assigned2_row" class="nykRow">
<tr class="nykRow">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You would need to navigate to your popup.  Can you paste the html which contains the email, firstname etc objects..

Comment: Check the presence of `frame` in the pop up.

Comment: @Manigandan - I have posted all the relavant code. Based on thatat, can you please let me know how to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "**Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert()**" statement you will have to use "**driver.switchTo().activeElement()**".This is the solution of your problem.